# orientdb 2.2.26 cluster setup - queries hang

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb2.2

```
Orientdb version - 2.2.26  
CLuster - 3 node setup, readQuorum = 2, writeQuorum = "majority", ridBag.embeddedToSbtreeBonsaiThreshold = 2147483647  
Nodes - CentOS 7.0, 24 cores and 96 GB RAM
Gremlin-scala/tinkerpop APIs are used for querying and inserting.
```

This code works fine on single node setup.

Code checks for existing vertex in graph. If vertex does not exist, then the insert operation are batched and send to the db within a transaction.

I see following warnings in orientdb log on all three nodes -

```
2017-09-15 16:37:31:025 WARNI [dev2] Timeout (852567ms) on waiting for synchronous responses from nodes=[dev1, dev3, dev2] responsesSoFar=[] request=(id=1.354 task=record_read(#65:22)) [ODistributedDatabaseImpl]  
2017-09-15 16:52:18:239 WARNI [dev2] Timeout (1049042ms) on waiting for synchronous responses from nodes=[dev1, dev3, dev2] responsesSoFar=[] request=(id=1.568 task=record_read(#63:24)) [ODistributedDatabaseImpl]  
2017-09-15 17:25:22:477 WARNI [dev2] Timeout (1984236ms) on waiting for synchronous responses from nodes=[dev1, dev3, dev2] responsesSoFar=[] request=(id=1.889 task=record_read(#63:24)) [ODistributedDatabaseImpl]
```

There is no problem on network. Firewall is disabled on all three nodes.

Are these logs related to the problem ?

What else I should check to fix the problem ?

Comment: I did setup of another cluster with three machines, found same problem on this setup too. Enabled FINE log on server and saw that responses are timing out. I decided to use newer version of orientdb 2.2.27. Everything works fine in this version. So there must be some bug in 2.2.26 running in distributed mode.

Comment: While debugging I tried to set storage.openFiles.limit in orientdb-server-config.xml but the value does not change and it remains 512.

Comment: My first comment is not correct. The readQuorum was set to 1. This is the reason it worked. I realised that and set readQuorum to 2. The problem persists with 2.2.27 too.

Comment: Have you tried with 3.X version of OrientDB?